# Food contamination

Tags: food

1.Almost all the restaurants in my area don’t sell halal slaughtered meat(chicken/mutton)so if I eat veg in these restaurants do I always need to ask them about the utensils they use for preparing the veg & non-veg food or just let it be as it might trigger my OCD?
2. Is the issue of contamination of food in Islam real as there is nothing specifically written about it in the hadhees?

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help]. If Allah and the prophet didn't specify anything it is rather unlikely that such a ruling exists. Especially as the qur'an clearly allows us to eat food of people of the book. Further even in case of similar ruling we know that little contamination doesn't count as an issue. And Allah knows best.

Answer (score 0):

Eating halal in a restaurant that serves non-halal food is undesirable (makruh), sitting at a table where wine is served even without drinking it is forbidden (haram).

Note that chicken or mutton slaughtered by "people of the book" are declared acceptable.

Considerations for purity common to Orthodox Judaism are usually not applied in Islam, and an educated chef would not allow to cut all things without cleaning the knife.

However, voices that are strict in this regard exist

https://islamqa.org/hanafi/askmufti/44659/vegetarian-food-from-haraam-restaurant/

(Note that in spite of the strictness of the consideration, it doesn't go further than declaring it makruh)